# Evidence of Aztecs using Quetzal feathers as commodity money?

Tags: economy, aztec

I found some webpages on the internet stating that on Aztecs barter-based economy, the remainder of value between two goods (if any) was settled with, among others, Quetzal feathers.

Is there any evidence/documentation to support such statements? I do not have access to published books at the moment.

The webpage is: http://www7.uc.cl/sw_educ/historia/conquista/parte1/html/h53.html
(in spanish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the claim dubious, or at least incomplete.  Google reveals multiple citations to Aztec use of cocoa beans (I think the [Bank of Belgium](http://www.nbbmuseum.be/2013/03/kakao.htm) is among the best) as commodity currency, and none to feathers in the same role. I would have expected at least one mention of the alternative commodity currencies.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. Cocoa beans would be a bit harder to come by. Using something as common as feathers in the tropics would seem to invite inflation.